# Is Angular 4 javascript library or it is server-side library?

Tags: angular

Can please explain what is angular 4 ?

I know java servlets.

Is Angular 4 created to replace servlets? Or is it javascript library like AngularJS, jQuery?

**Edit**

if it is javascript library then why I need node.js installed, angular cli installed and even launch the server. These are first steps in getting started tutorial angular.io/guide/quickstart?

And what js file I have to include to be able to use angular in browser?

Comment: `Or is it javascript library like AngularJS, jQuery?` Yes.

Comment: it's a front-end javascript framework more than a library.

Comment: @RahulSingh No need to SHOUT.

Comment: @PeterB it worth it actually  , you can see it in nearly every answer . this causes a lot of problems for Developers . Angular 2 3 4 etc. Tell me if i am wrong

Comment: Can you look at my edits?

Answer (score 3):

> Angular is a platform that makes it easy to build applications with
>   the web. Angular combines declarative templates, dependency injection,
>   end to end tooling, and integrated best practices to solve development
>   challenges. Angular empowers developers to build applications that
>   live on the web, mobile, or the desktop

Angular is a javascript **libary** and **framework** for developing web applications.

More Informations https://angular.io/docs

Answer (score 1):

> Angular 4 is javascript **framework** for mobile and desktop but if you need server side rendering you can use Angular Universal.

This info is from the official page of Angular Universal:

> At a high level, there are two major pieces to the Angular Universal:
>
> - Rendering on the server which means generating all the HTML for a page at a given route
> - Transitioning from the server view to the client view in the browser client

*Server Rendering Flows with Angular Universal*

- Flow for server pre-rendering:

  1. Generate static HTML with build tool
  2. Deploy generated HTML to a CDN
  3. Server view served up by CDN
  4. Server view to client view transition (see below)
- Flow for server re-rendering:

  1. HTTP GET request sent to the server
  2. Server generates a page that contains rendered HTML and inline JavaScript for 3. Preboot (and you can optionally add serialized data for caching purposes)
  3. Server view to client view transition (see below)
- Flow for server view to client view transition:

  1. Browser receives initial payload from server
  2. User sees server view
  3. Preboot creates hidden div that will be used for client bootstrap and starts recording events
  4. Browser makes async requests for additional assets (i.e. images, JS, CSS, etc.)
  5. Once external resources loaded, Angular client bootstrapping begins
  6. Client view rendered to the hidden div created by Preboot
  7. Bootstrap complete, so Angular client calls preboot.done()
  8. Preboot events replayed in order to adjust the application state to reflect changes made by the user before Angular bootstrapped (i.e. typing in textbox, clicking button, etc.)
  9. Preboot switches the hidden client view div for the visible server view div
  10. Finally, Preboot performs some cleanup on the visible client view including setting focus

For more info:

- [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/overview/)
- [Angular](https://angular.io/features)